# Change speed depending on angular velocity

Tags: objective-c, math, cocos2d-iphone, velocity, angle

I scroll my background at a speed value of `float speed = 50;` I want to change this speed value depending on the angle of my sprite on the background, so it looks like the sprite is slowing down when it turns corners. All my accessors and mutators are set up, I just can't work out the formula which alters the background speed depending on the sprites angular velocity.

here is my mutator, whatever formula I use to give me value it'll be taken off every tick in my update method like this:

```
-(void) setSpeed:(float) value
{
    Speed -= value;
}
```

Then to actually get the background moving I use:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if (background.position.y < background2.position.y)
    {
        background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y - speed * delta);
        background2.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y - speed * delta);
        background.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
    }

    //reset
    if (background.position.y <-background.contentSize.height / 2)
    {
        background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2 ,background2.position.y + background2.contentSize.height);
    } 
    else if (background2.position.y < -background2.contentSize.height / 2)
    {
        background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I suppose a better way of doing this would be to make the speed value of the background be determined completely on a formula generated by the player sprites rotation, rather than me initialising speed at 50 to begin with, any thoughts for the formula?

Comment: omega being the rotation angle?

Comment: That is exponential I think. The higher the angle of the player sprite the faster the background moves, I need the opposite. I've edited the main block to show how I'm decreasing the value. I just don't know the formula to work that value out given the sprites angular velocity.

Comment: So you don't want the (tangential) speed of a circularily moving body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math time! :D

What you want is to find the y-component of a rotated vector. The vector has magnitude equal to your velocity (aka speed).

Ye olde reminder: SOH-CAH-TOA!

We'll want to use the CAH: *Cosine(angleInRadians) = Adjacent / Hypotenuse* ... In this case, the angle is known (the sprites rotation), the Hypotenuse is known (the sprite's simulated speed), and the Adjacent is the unknown speed of your background in the y direction. So, we solve for "Adjacent" ...

On to the code:

```
float spriteSpeed = 50.0;
...
float radians = -CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(yourSprite.rotation);
float backgroundYSpeed = cosf(radians) * spriteSpeed;
```

You could also simultaneously shift your background horizontally using Sine:

```
float backgroundXSpeed = sinf(radians) * spriteSpeed;
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate this, if I set the sprite speed to 100 it looks quite nice, except the sprites rotation can change quite quickly please check the output from my update method which prints the background speed:

http://pastebin.com/zNJPB373

Can I stop this going negative and changing so drastically with more maths? as the background jerks backwards if the change in angle is too big and too fast.

Thanks again

Comment: @Lewis It should only go negative if the sprite is rotated to point "backwards"... Make sure you aren't feeding it the change in angle, just feed cosf() the sprite's current rotation.